# Final variables within anonymous classes

Tags: java, final, anonymous-inner-class

I have an anonymous class which takes the iterated value from a collection as shown below. With this code, is that immediate variable `in` preserved within anonymous class? Or different threads can take same `in` value?

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    list.add(i);

for (final Integer in : list) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(value + "," + in);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: I don't find it particularly clear what you're asking.  In this case,  you are passing a different value of `in` to each of 20 threads.  Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: My question is that can two threads share same value?

Comment: Also I thought the iteration on collection is implicitly converted into normal for loop with same variable for the iteration. So I was confused whether a new 'in' variable is created every time when we iterate on the collection.

Comment: Yes, two threads can share the same value, but in your particular example, they don't.  `in` is iterating through a list, in other words, it will take each value from the list in turn.  The objects referenced by `in` don't need to be created each time, since they already exist in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each value of `in` is preserved in each of the `Thread`s that is created.  You can use a local variable in an anonymous inner class as long as it's declared `final`, or if you're using Java 8, if it's "effectively final" (not `final` but not changed).